# populate from from jquery serialized string

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Ive serialized a form using jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnsubmit", function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/RiskScore",
    type: "post",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        $('.content-wrap').html(result);
    }
});
```

});

And i want to deserialize this and populate the form on the next page. How can i do this?

Comment: what next page, it's submitted with ajax ?

Comment: it is a html.beginform that is submited with a button with id "btnsubmit"

Answer (score 0):

**jquery.unserialize.js**

```
/**
 * $.unserialize
 *
 * Takes a string in format "param1=value1&param2=value2" and returns an object { param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2' }. If the "param1" ends with "[]" the param is treated as an array.
 *
 * Example:
 *
 * Input:  param1=value1&param2=value2
 * Return: { param1 : value1, param2: value2 }
 *
 * Input:  param1[]=value1&param1[]=value2
 * Return: { param1: [ value1, value2 ] }
 *
 * @todo Support params like "param1[name]=value1" (should return { param1: { name: value1 } })
 */
(function($){
    $.unserialize = function(serializedString){
        var str = decodeURI(serializedString);
        var pairs = str.split('&');
        var obj = {}, p, idx, val;
        for (var i=0, n=pairs.length; i < n; i++) {
            p = pairs[i].split('=');
            idx = p[0];

            if (idx.indexOf("[]") == (idx.length - 2)) {
                // Eh um vetor
                var ind = idx.substring(0, idx.length-2)
                if (obj[ind] === undefined) {
                    obj[ind] = [];
                }
                obj[ind].push(p[1]);
            }
            else {
                obj[idx] = p[1];
            }
        }
        return obj;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

https://gist.github.com/rcmachado/242617

Comment: How does it fill my other form?